# "0xFFFF &" in array index, what does this mean?

Tags: c++, cuda

I saw something like

```
somearray[0xFFFF & bi]
```

in a C++/CUDA code, I wonder what does this mean?

Comment: `0xFFFF` is a hexadecimal [integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) with value 65535, and `&` is a [bitwise logic operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators) "AND". The effect of `0xFFFF & bi` is that only the 16 least significant bits of `bi` will be used as the index.

Comment: The `&` here is a `bitwise and` operation. In this case, it takes last two bytes from `bi` and annuls everything else.

Comment: @heap underrun and ALX23z thanks a lot for the quick response, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

In general, the operations `x % y` and `x & (y-1)` are equivalent if `y` is a power of two.

This is the case for your code snipped. Thus,
`somearray[0xFFFF & bi]` is equivalent to `somearray[bi % 65536]` which means only the first 65536 array entries will be accessed, but with wrap-around for values of `bi` which are larger than 65535.

The computation of a bitwise AND is more efficient than plain modulo computation. However, modern compilers should perform this transformation automatically if the righthanded side of modulo is a power of two compile-time constant. I would prefer writing `x % 65536` for readability.

Comment: does "0xFFFF & bi" == "65535 & bi" == "bi % 65536"?

Answer (score 2):

The index of the array (`somearray`) will be calculated as follows:

1. `0xFFFF` equals `65535` decimal, which equals `16` times binary `1`s (`1111111111111111`)
2. your bi variable will also be 'represented' in binary
3. The two will be `AND`ed together and you have your index calculated. If `bi` is less then `16` bit integer, then the index will equal bi, or else, it will be the lesser `16` bit of `bi` - or else, if it is not of type `integer`, you will get compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

This means:

use low 16 bits of `bi` as `somearray` 's index.